# disabling Devise registration for production environment only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration, production-environment

I am launching a beta site with a select group of users. I want to disable registration in the production environment only, and only for a short period of time (i.e. I don't want to nuke my registration altogether). I know I can simply hide the "sign up" link, but I suspect that hackers smarter than I can still use the RESTful routes to accomplish registrations. What's the best way to disable registration so my test/development environments still work, but production is affected? Thanks for any pointers.

I've tried pointing named scopes in such a way that "sign_up" goes to "sign_in", but it didn't work. Here's what I've tried:

```
devise_scope :user do
    get "users/sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :sign_in
    get "users/sign_up", :to => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :sign_up
end
```

Ideally, we'd send the user to a "pages#registration_disabled" page or something like that. I just wanted to get something working I can play around with.

EDIT:
I've changed the model as requested, then added the following to /spec/user_spec.rb

```
describe "validations" do
    it "should fail registration if in production mode" do
      ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "production"
      @user = Factory(:user).should_not be_valid
    end
end
```

it is passing as "true" rather than false. Is there a way to mock up the production environment? I'm just spit-balling this one.

Thanks!

Comment: I've just learned that `RAILS_ENV` was deprecated and that it's preferred to use `Rails.env`

The strategy I'd use is something like `if Rails.env.production?` set some constant to true, then in the test, simply test for the constant.

Comment: is it possible to run RSPEC in test mode but have it pretend it is production? like set Rails.env?

Comment: You could pretty much just add `if Rails.env.production? or Rails.env.test?` in the model and solve it that way.

Comment: ok. i was hoping to be able to test before deploying... i'm pretty new :)

Comment: Yeah test first is always the way to go.

Comment: Worth noting that removing :registrable breaks the named routes for both creating *and* editing registrations.  This is probably more than the desired effect.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Since others are having the problem I'm having (see my comments).  Here is exactly how I fixed it.  I used murphyslaw's idea.  But you also need to make sure devise uses your new controller for the registration routing, or it won't do much for you.

Here is my controller override:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    flash[:info] = 'Registrations are not open yet, but please check back soon'
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def create
    flash[:info] = 'Registrations are not open yet, but please check back soon'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I've added flash messages to inform anyone who somehow stumbles upon the registration page why it isn't working.

Here is what is in my `routes.rb`

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" } 
  else
    devise_for :users
  end
```

The controllers hash specifies that I want it to use my overridden registrations controller.

Anyways, I hope that saves someone some time.

Comment: No because it inherits from `Devise:RegistrationsController` which contains all of the routes handlers.  All I've done is override the create route.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me in production - this does - thanks.

Comment: And hello from Vancouver as well ;-) Don't think we've met, but we have mutual acquaintances.

Comment: Good answer! I'm using this myself. One note: Since rails v2.2.1 you can use `Rails.env.production?` instead of `Rails.env == 'production'`.

Comment: Yes I usually do that these days. Updated the answer since it looks nicer.

Comment: Thank's Chris Nicola!

Answer (score 103):

Edit the `user` model and remove `:registerable`, I think that should give you what you want.

**Edit:**

I think this would work:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
else
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :registerable 
end
```

Comment: That would remove for all environments tho, right? is there a way to specify by environment at the model level?

Comment: Didn't need this, but discovered I could use "Rails.env" in models. Priceless :) Thanks.

Comment: As per Chris Nicola's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8291318/9344, this will disable the ability to editing registrations which is probably more than the desired effect (definitely was in my case).

Comment: How to disable /users/sign_in under production?

Answer (score 11):

Only remove `:registerable` will not solve the problem. If you have some routes in your view you will get an error:

`undefined local variable or method 'edit_user_registration_path'`

Take care of this.

Comment: a restart of the app may also be needed

Answer (score 6):

you could override the Devise::RegistrationsController and the create action to redirect to the page you want. The Controller should probably look something like this:

```
class User::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    redirect_to your_page_path if Rails.env.production?
  end

end
```

Comment: This is important, since disabling :registerable breaks both edit and create registration routes. So if you are testing in production with users you have already created disabling :registrable can cause a bunch of problems

Comment: Exactly. I actually had to kill my register route for production. i'll give this a try as I rebuild some of the core features of my site. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to call `super` in case this is not production.