# ruby on rails devise :registrable remove return errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to **remove** the **registration page** from my rails app since i am going with **invitation only system** and i have read that i have to remove the `:registrable` module from my user model in order for my sign up page to disappear...

when i do it i get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#new

undefined method `new_with_session' for #<Class:0x007ffb53b8f820>
```

here is the devise line from **user.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to override the registration controller also.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    flash[:info] = 'Registrations are not open yet, but please check back soon'
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def create
    flash[:info] = 'Registrations are not open yet, but please check back soon'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I got it from   [disabling Devise registration for production environment only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370164/disabling-devise-registration-for-production-environment-only)

Comment: still can't see any difference in production or development server... all work the same

Comment: i had to create a devise folder in the controllers folder in order for it to work thanks

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to remove the :registrable from the model. The error described will occur until you restart the application

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this is quite some time now, but it doesn't stop anyone from running into the same problem since I just experienced this few minutes ago.

**The best solution** is just to **restart** your application after removing `:registrable` from your model such

`devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :registrable`

becomes

`devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable`.

**But if you still somewhat wants to carry people along why Sign Up is not available**, I will advice anyone to go with the accepted answer.

Thanks.